# Google App engine Internal Server Error

Tags: python, web-applications

This code responds with a 500 Internal Server Error, but I cannot locate the problem.

```
class Customer(ndb.Model):
 # Because we will use email address as an ID/key, no need to define it.
 name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
 registered = ndb.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
 def toJSON(self):
     jsondata = {
     "email" : self.key.id(),
     "name" : self.name,
     "registered" : str(self.registered)
     }
     return json.encode(jsondata)       

class NewCustomerHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
     # Assuming values to create a customer are passed in query variables..
     email = self.request.get('email')
     name = self.request.get('name')
     callback = self.request.get('callback')
     cust = Customer(id=email)
     cust.name = name
     cust.put() # The customer is now in the database
     self.response.write(callback + '({"response":“Customer added”})')
         self.response.write(callback+'({"response":"Not found."})')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/cust', NewCustomerHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: *I cannot locate the problem* luckily, the error shows exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your application logs should make the issue much easier to troubleshoot.

In this specific instance though, your app might be crashing because of the improper indentation you have here:

```
 self.response.write(callback + '({"response":“Customer added”})')
     self.response.write(callback+'({"response":"Not found."})')
```

Comment: Thanks this helped however relised that the qoutation marks are different